# OpenCV program wouldn't compile on Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv

I am trying to compile a very simple OpenCV (2.4.9) program in Visual Studio 2010 just to check whether opencv libraries have been linked properly. Here is the program code I am trying to run.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char** argv )
{
    Mat image;
    image = imread( "MyPic.jpg", 1 );

    if ( !image.data )
    {
        printf("No image data \n");
        return -1;
    }
    namedWindow("Display Image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    imshow("Display Image", image);

    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

But when I press the build button, the compilation fails and shows the following error.

> 1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'opencv_gpu249.lib'

What the problem could be? How to solve it?

[image]

Comment: how did that lib get into your linker settings ? (the prebuild opencv libs don't come with gpu support)

Comment: Which lib files should I add to linker settings...

Comment: opencv_core249.lib opencv_highgui249.lib

Comment: Now I am getting this error... `1>opencv_highgui249.lib(opencv_highgui249.dll) : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86'`  I am using 64bit

Comment: see @herohuyongtao 's answer below. (choose the x64 folder)

Comment: I am using the x64 folders only... Even then I am getting the errors

Comment: The problem is that you are using x64 folders but building for Win32. The combobox next to the Debug combobox reads Win32 not x64.

Comment: @drescherjm Yes, that was the problem this time... The solution platform was Win32 not x64. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the OpenCV library path to the Visual Studio's **Library Directories**:

```
OpenCV-2.4.9-Path\build\x86\vc10\lib
```

or for 64bits

```
OpenCV-2.4.9-Path\build\x64\vc10\lib
```